# Run code automatically in the background as soon as Office JS add-in is sideloaded in Office Client

Tags: office-js

According to what I have learned while working with Office JS add-ins is that it is only possible to run JavaScript code only when some kind of action is initiated by the user manually on the Office client application (Word, Excel etc) such as by clicking on the button on the ribbon, or after loading the web page in the task pane.

I have a scenario where I need to run a background script as soon as the add-in is loaded in Office client app, and let it running until the client application has been closed, without having the user to interact with the add-in. I wanted to know if there is a way to make it work somehow, or any workarounds to achieve something similar? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REVISED ANSWER:
I'm afraid that there is no way to do that with Office Add-ins and office.js. There is no way to handle the sideloading event.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:
Try putting your code inside the onReady() method or Office.initialize(). It will run immediately after Office initializes. For details, see [Initializing your add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office#initializing-your-add-in) and [Loading the DOM and runtime environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/loading-the-dom-and-runtime-environment).

Comment: Yes, you are right, but Office.initialize code only runs once we render our web application html page on any Office control such as Task Pane or dialog box, and it stops executing as soon as we close those controls. I'm using react for my add-in and I have my Office.initialize code in index.tsx file

Comment: To open Task Pane or Dialog Box, we need user to perform some operation, and I do not want that.

Comment: OK. I understand better now. I will change my answer. The bad news is that there's no way to do that.

Comment: So it is not possible to run your JavaScript as soon as the add-in is sideloaded. But let's say that user does some action in response to which the page is loaded in a browser control and Javascript starts executing, but as soon as that browser control is closed, Javascript stops executing as well. Is there a way for a Javascript code to keep executing in the background? One use case could be to keep the session alive for the user.

Comment: Is there still no way to do this?